# If $f$ is continuous and $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$, then $f(x) = cx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

> Assume $f$ is a function over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f$ is continuous, then $f(x) = cx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

I find it hard to use the definition of continuity to derive anything from the equation. I think we could write the definition of the limit in terms to get $$\forall \epsilon,\exists \delta \quad 0<|x-a|<\delta \quad \implies \quad |f(x)-L| < \epsilon.$$
I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You don't need to continuity for the rationals.

Comment: @Wilf-Fine Typo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: If you can show that it is true for all rational x, you can use the information that f(x) is continuous to fill in the reals.

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate Q but I don't feel like searching.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$. This implies that $f(0)=0$.

Write $f(1)=c$, let $n>0$ be an integer, recursively, show that $f(n)=nc$.

This implies that $f(n-n)=0=f(n)+f(-n)$. Deduce that $f(-n)=c(-n)$. Thus, $n\in Z$ implies $f(n)=cn$.

$f(q(1/q)=qf(1/q)=c$ thus $f(1/q)=c/q$, $f(p/q)=pf(1/q)=cp/q, p,q\in Z$.

If you want the result for $R$, every real $x$ is a limit of a sequence $(x_n)$ of rational, since $f$ is continuous, $f(x)=lim_nf(x_n)=lim_ncx_n=cx$.

Comment: Your statement that $f(n) = nc$ holds for $n$ rational as well.

Comment: Certainly, I have shown in it by showing $f(p/q) =cp/q$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Check that the claim holds for integers. Let $f(1) = \alpha$. Then use the relation to show that $f(m) = m \alpha$ for all integers.

Show that in fact the above result holds for rational numbers.

Use the fact that continuity in a metric space is equivalent to sequential continuity.

Use that every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers together with continuity to conclude the result.