# Can we draw the conclusion that this function must be linear?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $f\left(\alpha x+\left(1-\alpha\right)x'\right)=\alpha f\left(x\right)+\left(1-\alpha\right)f\left(x'\right)$, $\forall \alpha \in \left[0,1\right]$ and $\forall x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

And if so, how to prove it?

Thank you very much!

Edit: Why am I get down-voted? Does this question violate some rules or it is too simple or something? I am confused.

My attempt is below: I thought "linear function" means $\exists b_0, b_1, ..., b_n$ such that $f\left(x\right)=b_0+b_1 x_1+...+b_n x_n$. But I have totally no idea what can be the "upstream" step, that is, what do I need to prove first, and then it follows $f$ is linear.

Comment: perhaps include your attempt?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I failed to have any meaningful attempt...I mean, a linear function satisfies the conditions given, but I got totally lost to prove it is the only one. There are infinitely many possible forms of functions, so I don't even know where to start if I was trying to use proof by contradiction...

Comment: You just have to verify that it satisfies the conditions for linearity. Being linear doesn't mean you can't have other properties. You are encouraged to edit your post to include your attempt.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you for the hint. But I am still confused. I tried to impose $f$ on both sides of your hint, but then I get stuck because neither side is in a form of a convex combination...

Comment: @Ypbor your function doesn't have to be linear. See my response below.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a very good question, don't get discouraged by some people. The word you really want to use is "affine" instead of "linear", but many people use them interchangebly in informal discussion.

Note that adding a constant to $f$ preserves the property you mentioned, so you only need to consider all $f$ such that

(1) $f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) x') = \alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha)f(x')$ for all $x$, $x'$, and $\alpha\in[0, 1]$.

(2) $f(0) = 0$

and show that $f$ can be written as $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i$ -- that is, a "linear function".

(This is actually equivalent to a very fundamental question: is the dual space of an Eucliean space isomorphic to itself? More generally, one can ask, given a vector space, what is its (algebraic/topological) dual? In the Euclidean case, the duals are just the space itself; but things can become very tricky when it comes to infinite-dimensional vector spaces.)

Old Hint: Let $V^*$ be the set of all $f$ that satisfies (1) and (2). First show that $V^*$ is a vector space; then try to design a basis for $V^*$ and prove that it is indeed a basis. Finally, observe that any linear combination of the basis vectors you designed is in the form of $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i$.

New Hint:
Let $f\in V^*$ and $(f_1,⋯,f_n)$ be the basis you described in the first comment, and let $b_i=f(e_i)$ where $e_i$ has 1 in the ith coordinate and 0 everywhere else. You can try to show that $f=b_i f_i$ by showing that these two functions agree on $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n$ (and consequently by linearity agree on the entire primal space $V$, which is $R^n$ here).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think $V^*$ is a vector space. As for the basis, I think it is $f_i\left(x_1, ..., x_n\right)=x_i, i=1, ..., n$. But proving this is a basis is exactly the same as my original question. So this is again where I get stuck.

Comment: I tried to mimic the trick in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734170/if-f-is-continuous-and-fxy-fxfy-then-fx-cx-for-all-x-in. But in that case, when one uses the assumed feature for $x$ and $x$, we get $f(2x)=2f(x)$. While in my case, it is just $f\left(x\right)=f(x)$, which is an identity, so iteration does not work.

Comment: +1 "affine"  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: Thank you for the new hint. I think the objective is to prove $f\left(x_1, ..., x_n\right)=x_1f\left(1, 0, ..., 0\right)+...+x_n f\left(0, ..., 0, 1\right)$. But I think that the convex combination condition can only ensure this is true when the sum of $x_i$ is 1. I feel that another key condition, that is, $f\left(cx\right)=cf\left(x\right)$, is missing. It seems that this is another way of expressing my concern in my second comment.

Comment: Ah, maybe by constructing a convex combination between $(x_1,  ..., x_n)$ and $(0, ..., 0)$, I can solve this problem...

Comment: Yes, that is what the old hint is for. When you prove $V^*$ is a vector space you get $f(cx) = cf(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ need not be linear. Take $f(x,y)=x+y+1$. Then $f$ isn't linear. However, $$\begin{eqnarray*}f\Big(t(x_0,y_0)+(1-t)(x_1,y_1)\Big)&=&f\Big(tx_0+(1-t)x_1,ty_0+(1-t)y_1\Big) \\ &=&t(x_0+y_0)+(1-t)(x_1+y_1)+1\end{eqnarray*}$$ Meanwhile, $$\begin{eqnarray*}tf(x_0,y_0)+(1-t)f(x_1,y_1)&=&t(x_0+y_0+1)+(1-t)(x_1+y_1+1) \\ &=&t(x_0+y_0)+(1-t)(x_1+y_1)+1\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I see your point. But I think it is linear. The definition in my attempt is incorrect (the intercept term is missing). My bad, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ypbor my function $f$ is not linear but it satisfies your conditions.